# Ionic States with params

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a state that will provide 5 states based on a parameter.

Here is app.js:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
$stateProvider

.state('home' , {
    url:'/',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
.state('car' , {
    url:'/car/:carId',
    templateUrl: 'car{{carId}}.html',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
        $scope.carId = $stateParams.carId;
    }
  });
})
```

The url with id works but how can I do the same for template url for the html page as now all 5 of my list item states display same content.

List with 5 items where I call state example:

```
<a class="item" ui-sref="car({ carId: 1})">
   Car 1
</a>
```

The problem is in script definition for id of templateUrl:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="car{{carId}}.html">
  <ion-view view-title="Car 1"> 
    <ion-content>
        <h1>car1</h1>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

Is it possible to pass that carId in script definition for id and app.js templateUrl so then each page would have different content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your templateUrl with a function as described in the [ui-router wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates) :

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts', {
  templateUrl: function ($stateParams){
    return '/car' + $stateParams.carId + '.html';
  }
})
```